# Can Gradle + Artifactory support 5-component version numbers?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

Our internal numbering scheme has five components to a version number, e.g.: `1.22.333.4444.55555`.

Is this supported by Artifactory? By Gradle?

This is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598207/how-to-configure-a-longer-version-number-in-artifactory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by "supported".

***Is it easily doable? Yes.*** Because a Gradle version declaration is a simple **Groovy String variable assignment** and Artifactory accepts the resolution and deployment of all artifacts **regardless of their path**.

The version scheme makes a difference only when it isn't standard, you want Artifactory to recognize it as part of a valid module and perform different operations beyond simple deployment and resolution, operations that rely on module recognition; in this case you can ["teach"](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) Artifactory how to recognize your layout.

Comment: Thanks very much!  The operations I wonder about (from studying Maven, with no Gradle/Artifactory experience) the most are wild-carding (e.g, "1.22.333.4444.*") and any essential built-in operations that increment revision numbers.  Do you have any thoughts about these?  If not, I'm fine - this is enough for me to start digging for myself.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by wild-carding; when resolving?
Also, incrementing build number depends on the situation; with release artifacts it should be part of the promotion; with integration artifacts it's normally a timestamp or a running integer. All these can be done in Gradle because basically a Groovy script.

Comment: Yes, by wild-carding I mean resolution of a "*" in a version number.